# Functions inside functions in C

Tags: c, function

I'm making a code that is similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double some_function( double x, double y)
{
  double inner_function(double x)
  { 
    // some code
    return x*x;
  }

  double z;
  z = inner_function(x);
  return z+y;

}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%f\n", some_function(2.0, 4.0));
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles perfectly in GCC (with no warnings) but fails to compile in ICC.

ICC gives:

```
main.c(16): error: expected a ";"
    { 
    ^

main.c(21): warning #12: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error
    double z;
            ^

main.c(22): error: identifier "z" is undefined
    z = inner_function(x);
    ^

compilation aborted for main.c (code 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

(edit) Sorry for the poor example. In my original code I kinda need to do this stuff. I'm using a GSL numerical integrator and have something like:

```
double stuff(double a, double b)
{
  struct parameters
  {
    double a, b;
  };

  double f(double x, void * params)
  {
    struct parameters p = (struct parameters *) params;
    double a = p->a, b = b->b;
    return some_expression_involving(a,b,x);
  }
  struct parameters par = {a,b};

  integrate(&f, &par);

}
```

And I have lots of functions with this kind of structure: they are the result of an integration of a functions with lots of external parameters. And the functions that implements numerical integration must receive a pointer to a function of type:

```
double f(double x, void * par)
```

I would really like functions to be nested this way so my code doesn't bloat with lots and lots of functions. And I hope I could compile it with ICC to speed things a bit.

Comment: You guys rocks!! In less then 2 minutes I had complete answers!!

Comment: Yo dawg, I herd you like functions...

Comment: This is why I need lambda expressions in C. :(

Comment: Concerning, "I don't see why you really need nested functions at all.", the reason more people are moving towards this style of development is to move towards JavaScripts namespacing and scoping mechanisms.  A function encapsulates other functions, and exposes functions through a structure.  Whether this simplifies development or future library use, I have yet to see.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Everybody else has given you the canonical answer "Nested functions are not allowed in standard C" (so any use of them depends on your compiler).

Your revised example is:

```
double stuff(double a, double b)
{
  struct parameters
  {
    double a, b;
  };

  double f(double x, void * params)
  {
    struct parameters p = (struct parameters *) params;
    double a = p->a, b = b->b;
    return some_expression_involving(a,b,x);
  }
  struct parameters par = {a,b};

  return integrate(&f, &par);     // return added!
}
```

Since you say that the functions such as the integrator need

> ```
>   double (*f)(double x, void * par);
> ```

I don't see why you really need nested functions at all.  I would expect to write:

```
struct parameters
{
    double a, b;
};

static double f(double x, void *params)
{
    struct parameters p = (struct parameters *) params;
    double a = p->a, b = b->b;
    return some_expression_involving(a,b,x);
}

double stuff(double a, double b)
{
    struct parameters par = { a, b };
    return integrate(f, &par);
}
```

The code above should work in C89 (unless there's an issue with initializing 'par' like that) or C99; this version of the code is for C99 only, using a compound literal for the parameter (section 6.5.2.5 Compound literals):

```
double stuff(double a, double b)
{
    return integrate(f, &(struct parameters){a, b});
}
```

The chances are excellent that you have only a few variations on the 'struct parameters' type.  You do need to provide separate (sufficiently) meaningful names for the various functions - you can only have one function called '`f`' per source file.

The only marginal, tiny benefit of the nested function version is that you can be sure that no other function than `stuff` calls `f`.  But given the example code, that is not a major benefit; the static definition of `f` means that no function outside this file can call it unless passed a pointer to the function.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 

my rationale for using nested functions was that, since f is not user anywhere except to calculate the integral, I thought this was a good way to make the code more readable for myself. But maybe not. 

I have many functions to integrate (it is actually a solution of a system of coupled equations in which each equation is an integral) I thought that leaving functions that are used only once floating through the code was bad practice. 

If I could use lambda functions as in python or Haskell it would be swell. But I need speed for this problem and don't know sufficient Haskell.

Answer (score 31):

Nested functions are available as a [language extension in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html), but they are not part of the standard language, so some compilers will not allow them.

Comment: +1 - a quick note for the OP: I think you're getting the error in GCC even though it supports nested functions because you've misspelled the function name.  inner_funcion() should be inner_function().

Comment: I see. Thanks for the VERY quick answer. 

I was using this without noticing it wasn't standard. That's very bad. I see my code will be very difficult to understand if I stick to using icc.

Comment: The last time I moved from JavaScript to C, I tried using nested functions. I love nested functions. But don't give up on making your C easy to read, understand, and debug. It's doable.

Answer (score 8):

C doesn't have nested functions. GCC's nested functions are an extension to the language.

Your runtime error in GCC is a spelling error. `inner_funcion` should be `inner_function`.

Comment: Oh.Oops. Thanks, I corrected the name of the function.

Comment: Why in the world did they add such a non-standard extension to C? Is there a compiler switch to turn it off?

Comment: Not sure. Probably. I remember I had the choice to enable them in XCode when I started iPhone development. I decided not to enable. I love nested functions, but to me one of the great advantages of straight C is portability.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of how to write ISO C90 portable code.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by many answers above, inner functions are not supported in C. However, inner *classes* can be used in C++ to accomplish a similar thing.  Unfortunately, they are a bit unwieldy to use, but it might be an option for you if you don't mind compiling as C++.

Untested example:

```
double some_function( double x, double y)
{
  struct InnerFuncs
  {
    double inner_function(double x)
    { 
      // some code
      return x*x;
    }
    // put more functions here if you wish...
  } inner;

  double z;
  z = inner.inner_function(x);
  return z+y; 
}
```

Note that this answer shouldn't imply that I think inner functions are a good idea in the usage you've shown.

Years-later edit:

C++ now allows us to use lambdas as inner functions.  In the case of my toy example above, it would look much like this:

```
double some_function( double x, double y)
{
   auto inner_function = [&]() { return x * x; }
   
   double z;
   z = inner_function ();
   return z + y;
}
```

Note the local variable x is automatically captured inside of the lambda, which is a very nice feature.

More here: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Would the loss of efficiency if I use this C++ code instead of my original C code be important?

Comment: I doubt there would be any significant or noticeable loss of efficiency.

Comment: This is pretty cool! It's almost like I have javascript's inner functions again!

Answer (score 3):

You are using nested functions - C does not support such things.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid C code, inner functions are not supported in C

Answer (score 1):

local function definitions inside a function are illegal in C.

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions are not part of the C standards. There is therefore no guarantee that it will work for all compilers and should definitely be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

In the event you were wondering how to turn off GCC extensions and such.

You can use the `-ansi` flag which essentially sets the standard to c89, and turns off GCC features which are incompatible with ISO C90.

See the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) for more information. Check out the `-std` flag too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I'm willing to bet this is either explicitly not allowed or undefined by the C99 spec, so it's probably best to stay away from it.