# Functions inside functions

Tags: c, macros, inline

if I do:

```
void foo() {
    if( .. ) {
      inline int baa(..) { return .. }
    } else {
      inline int baa(..) { return .. }
    }

}
```

And call: `baa(..)` inside `foo` function I get `implicit declaration of 'baa'`. 
But if I do prototype declaration: `inline int baa(int);` the error is `inline function 'baa' declared but never defined`. I'm using inline function to replace macro-function.

How to fix this?

**EDIT**
better: can someone explain why the compiler claims the above error message?

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957592/functions-inside-functions-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using inline function to replace macro-function.

You cannot *define* functions inside functions, you can only *declare* them. Declaring them makes their names visible in that scope but those functions still need a definition somewhere, and we know we cannot define them within another function. That's why the compiler says that the function was *declared* but never *defined*.

Instead, simply *declare* your functions `inline` at a global scope.

Comment: when you say "declare your functions inline at a global scope" did you mean `void myfunction()` or `void myfunction() { .. }`. But anyway,in this case, `baa` is declared dynamically depeding of a if-else condition. It's a try to replace to `if(..) #define foo(x) .. else #define foo(y)` that did not works for macros.

Comment: @Jack: `void myfunction()` is a _declaration_, `void myfunction(){ ... }` is a _definition_. A `#define` inside an `if` is not guarded by the conditional, so your function is not being declared dynamically. In fact, the _C preprocessor_ knows nothing about `if`, `else`, nor any other construct from the _C language_...

Comment: You are right. Now I see that it's bit no-sense what I have tried with macro-function. It will be defined anyway. But about inline functions, it's applied to it as well? Consider this code: http://pastebin.com/KurNMF51 I want to do something like this. The printf(), could to print `2`.

Comment: @Jack: No, not like that. Perhaps you can leverage _function pointers_?

Comment: @K-ballo: But  do I need point to another existing function or I can do `baa = &((arg){ return ..})` gcc-extensions are very appreciated too.

Comment: @Jack: You would need to point to existing functions, yes. I wouldn't know about _non-standard extensions_, I avoid them like the plague...

Comment: I usually avoid them too,but sometimes I open an exception to gcc-extensions. :) Thanks very much. I accepted your question.

Comment: @K-ballo: Do you consider it's bad designer? http://pastebin.com/RBqTjE3i it are inside a loop, but too inside a if-condition that run only one time, after it a break is called.

Comment: The `foo` in if-statement and `int etc = foo();` was a typo only.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not part of the standard, you could compile with the flag `-fnested-functions`

Comment: hm.. it's for GCC? does not works for me(I'm using MinGW): `unrecognzided command line option -fnested-functions`

Comment: It's not available for gcc on windows.But your answer is valid yet! Thanks and +1.

Answer (score 1):

K-ballo's suggestion indeed seems best, but he didn't actually point out the problem.

A nested function, defined in a block, is valid only within the block. Just like a normal variable. You define one function in the `if` clause, and another in the `else` clause, and each is valid within that clause. But neither is valid after the `if-else` has been closed.

It's exactly the same with variables:

```
if (a) {
    int x = 3;
} else {
    int x = 4;
}
// x isn't valid here.
```