# Declaring a function?

Tags: c, user-defined-functions

in C I am writing some of my very first exercises. Earlier on, I tried to declare a simple function inside of main and it comes with an error: "function definition is not allowed here". But I thought a function could be declared inside of main or outside, the only difference being the scope?? I have also read, in here, of other people writing functions inside of main, so why won't it let me do it?
thanks

Comment: You should show your code, otherwise nobody can help you. But note that in C you cannot *define* a function inside another.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957592/functions-inside-functions-in-c

Comment: Maybe use Pascal instead?  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can *declare* a function inside another function:

```
int main(void) {
    int foo(int); // declaration
    ...
}
```

But you can't *define* a function inside another function:

```
int main(void) {
    // Doesn't work.
    int foo(int x) {
        return x * 2;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, declaring functions inside other functions is a really unusual thing to do, and essentially never necessary.