# I keep getting this error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-value, nested-function

I already saw a question about it, more than one, but it did not really solve my problem. The code is bigger, but the problem is with this part. I have this thing:

```
int globalx=12;  
int globaly=10;

void Function (int measurex, int measurey)
    float thingx()
            {
            (((globalx/2)-measurex)/(globalx/2));
            }
    float totalx=globalx/(float)thingx;
    float totaly=globaly/2;
```

and there is something wrong with it that returns that error. globalx and globaly are,as the name suggests, two global variables. What am I doing wrong here? How can I write something that does what I do intend to do here?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things about your code:

- Replace `thingx` with `thingx()`.
- `Function` definition should be inside braces `{...}`.
- Define `thingx()` outside `Function` definition (compiler dependent, since [Nested functions are not allowed in standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957592/functions-inside-functions-in-c)).
- Add a `return` statement to the `thingx()` function.
- Add `int measurex` as an argument to `thingx()` function.
- In `Function`, after getting the values of totalx and totaly you are not doing anything with them (maybe you just didn't put the whole code of this function in your question).

Your functions definitions should look like this:

```
float thingx(int measurex)
{
    return (((globalx/2)-measurex)/(globalx/2));
}

void Function (int measurex, int measurey) {
    float totalx=globalx/(float)thingx(measurex);  // <-- missing parentheses, should be thingx(...)
    float totaly=globaly/2;

    // You probably want to do something with totalx and totaly here...
}
```

main:

```
int globalx=12;  
int globaly=10;

Function(globalx, globaly);
```

Also, keep in mind that this will truncate the result to an integer `globaly/2` since `globaly` is defined as **int** (You can read this about integer division: 
[What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c))

Comment: ok, but how `thingx()` is supposed to have access to `measurex`?

Comment: You are right! I just added that to the list and fixed the examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really messed up.  For your function you need to have all your code inside of braces {}.  Like this...

```
void myFunction(int a, int b)
{
    //put your code in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing, because, `thingx()` being a function, `thingx` is basically a function pointer, and you're trying to perform the division of a `float` with a function pointer.

---

First, let me declare clearly, [Nested functions are not standard `C`. They are supported as GCC extension.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Having said that, in your case, you need to

1. Move the `thingx()` function definition outside of `Function()`.
2. Just like you did for `thingx()` function, the body of `Function()` should also be inside `{...}`.
3. Use the function call operator `()` to call a function. So basically your statement should look like

   ```
   float totalx=globalx/(float)thingx(measurex);
   ```

   ad the function definition should look like

   ```
    float thingx(int measurex){..
   ```
4. Add a `return` statement to your function. As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.9.1

   > If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
   >   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

   so, the function body should look like

   ```
   {
       return (((globalx/2)-measurex)/(globalx/2));
   }
   ```