# Regex to find all calls of the certain function and NOT its declaration

Tags: c, regex

I need to write a regex which will match only lines with the C function call, not its declaration.

So, I need it to match only lines, where `funcName()` is not preceeded by `int`, `double`, `float`, `char` etc. and an arbitrary number of spaces.

---

The problem is, I can run into following expressions:

```
printf("Hello"); int f() {return 1;};
```

So I must consider even the situation, where there are some other characters before the date-type name.

```
myStruct f();
```

In this situation I want regex to match it, ONLY basic data-types should be excluded.

---

So far I've got to this expression:

```
^(?!(void|int|double|char))\s*f\(\).*$
```

But I have no idea, how to take care of the situation with characters before the type name.

Comment: If your line ends with semi-colon, it means it's not a function declaration, am I correct ?

Comment: You should be aware that any general solution needs to be hooked in between the preprocessor and the parser ( or must be a full-fledged preprocessor on its own ).

Comment: @collapsar I'm aware of that, I want to use it just for some very primitive cases.

Comment: Your example does not appear to be valid C. Should you be able to parse it nevertheless?

Comment: @RadLexus Not necessary, the parsed code will be valid. Did you mean the missing semicolon in the first example?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the cases you wish to cover? Note that C allows for arbitrary whitespace between tokens, so catching `int \n f();` would require you not to limit yourself to testing within single lines. ( `\n` meaning at least one physical newline character )

Comment: `int f() {..}` looks like a function declaration to me. While allowed in GCC as an extension, it [is not standard C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957592/functions-inside-functions-in-c). Also, a missing function argument. Also, the function after that declaration ought not to end with `};`.

Comment: Functions can return structs and typedef types, so `myStruct f();` looks more like a declaration than a call to me. Note that it is nigh impossible to parse the C grammar with regex. Whatever regex you come up with it most probably won't be able to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex meets your specs:

```
(^|((^|\s)(?!(void|int|double|char))[^\s]+)\s+)([a-zA-Z_]+\(\)?)
```

- The function name is defined by a character class containing letters and the underscore.
- The line starts with the function call, or
- the line contains at least one non-whitespace character before the function name. In that case ...

  - this non-WS sequence does not match the excluded keywords
  - there is at least 1 WS character before the function name

See the live demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aP4mR6/1).

**Caveat**

As several commentors have noted, ***this is not a robust solution***. It will work for a tightly constrained set of function call and declaration patterns only.

A general regex-based solution (if possible at all, which would heavily depend on the regex engine features available) will be of theoretical interest only as it had to mimic completely the C preprocessor.